# Using Neo4j database from C++

Tags: c++, neo4j

my problem is I want to use Neo4j database from a C++ program and I read a lot, but still don't know, how can I start.

First I would like to make a connection between Neo4j and C++, and I would like to create nodes from the C++ program.

Anyone have an example code, or can somebody help, how can I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no current C/C++ Neo4j drivers targeting Neo4j 2.x that I'm aware of. (See Stefan's answer for a C driver targeting the upcoming Neo4j 3.0 release)

However, using the [transactional Cypher API endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) you should be able to use any C++ http client / JSON parser to interact with Neo4j using Cypher.

Answer (score 8):

For the upcoming binary remoting protocol there's already a driver written in C, see:

- page: http://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/
- source: https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client

Please note that this will only work on Neo4j 3.0 builds. As of today, milestone-2 is the most current one. Be sure to read the release notes when working with milestones.

Comment: will this work in Windows C++ ?

Comment: @Antarus only testing through WSL2. Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install.